# Python 3.8. Не прерывать выполнение программы в случае ошибки. "Continue not properly in loop"

Tags: python, try-catch, continue

После того как универ перевели на удаленку и лекции стали читать онлайн, наш лектор захотел видеть от студентов обратную связь в виде полного конспекта. Лекцию читают быстро, а пишу я медленно, поэтому писать конспект вручную - не вариант. Переписывать с диктофона - извините, у меня и до этого работы хватало. Задачу нужно решить средствами автоматизации.

Я использую модуль для python, который называется speech_recognition. Мне нужно, чтобы программа работала в "поточном" режиме, раз за разом захватывая маленькие кусочки речи и преобразуя их в текст. Для этого я сначала зацикливал функцию, ответственную за процесс считывания-записи. Программа работала, но при тестировании обнаружилась маленькая неприятность: если алгоритм считывания звука встречал помехи (пение, нечленораздельную речь, длительное молчание), он выдавал ошибку типа speech_recognition.UnknownValueError и прерывал выполнение программы. Это означает, что в любой момент лекции программа может завершиться с ошибкой, а такого допустить нельзя.

Я заменил тело цикла, вызывающего функцию, на конструкцию try-except и установил команду continue в качестве инструкции на случай обнаружения ошибки. Программа перестала работать, а интерпретатор выдает только: "continue not properly in loop".

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибаюсь?

```
output_file = open("output.txt", "w")

def record_voice():
    recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
    with speech_recognition.Microphone(device_index = 1) as source:
        print('Записываю аудио')
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)
    query = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language = 'ru-RU')         
    print(f'Вы сказали: {query.lower()}')                                  #вывод текста в консоль
    output_file.writelines(f'{query}')                                     #вывод текста в файл

try:
    record_voice()
except:
    continue                                                               #not properly in loop

output_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`continue` может быть только в цикле, чтобы завершить программу используйте метод `exit`

```
try:
    record_voice()
except:
    exit()
```

---

Если вам надо вызывать `record_voice` пока она не завершить правильно, то надо добавить `while True` и `break`

```
while True:
    try:
        record_voice()
        break
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам за подсказку с циклом. Участок кода, начиная с "try:" и до  "continue" включительно я объединил в тело цикла "while i == 1:", где i = 1. Теперь программа работает так, как мне нужно. Спасибо.